# Inno how to add <Skip> button for optional wizard page?

Tags: inno-setup

I have an optional wizard page of TInputDirWizardPage type.
How to add  button which will not validate data and skip if data were not entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found simple and working solution. Instead of adding additional  button to avoid validation of empty path. I've just added default dir creation. in [Dirs] section.

```
[Dirs]
Name: {code:WrkGetWorkingDir}; Flags: uninsneveruninstall
```

My application could accept working dir cmdline arg or create default one if it is not specified. So. I just always specifying that cmdline arg and creating that default dir (if user did not changed that path) in installation script.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the inno help, here you see the available functions on the TInputDirWizardPage

```
TInputDirWizardPage = class(TWizardPage)
  function Add(const APrompt: String): Integer;
  property Buttons[Index: Integer]: TNewButton; read;
  property Edits[Index: Integer]: TEdit; read;
  property PromptLabels[Index: Integer]: TNewStaticText; read;
  property SubCaptionLabel: TNewStaticText; read;
  property Values[Index: Integer]: String; read write;
end;
```

I used this way only if i needed a text input on the page. I recommend you to create a complete custom WizardPage, with that you are more flexible. For the creation of the page you can use a designer, I created all my custom pages with the InnoSetup Form Designer. Here you can see it in action http://www.cenadep.org/2012/02/09/innosetup-form-designer/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
procedure OnClickMyButton(Sender: TObject);
begin
MsgBox('OnClickMyButton', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin

      if CurPageID = YourPageID.ID then
      begin
          MyButton := TButton.Create(YourPageID);
          MyButton.Parent := YourPageID.Buttons[0].Parent;
          MyButton.Top := YourPageID.Edits[0].Top + YourPageID.Edits[0].Height + 10;
          MyButton.Left := YourPageID.Edits[0].Left;
          MyButton.Width := 100;
          MyButton.Caption := 'My Custom Button';
          MyButton.OnClick  := @OnClickMyButton;           
      end; 
end;
```